# catch the value of a query string parameter in web performance test

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, testing, automated-tests

I have prepared a web performance test set. Firstly I recorded a new customer, so the customer got an id. I want to catch the value of this customer's id from the record to use it as a parameter at the second one. After the test I have seen the value of id at request tab under the query string parameters but i could not achieve to catch and record it to a file (xml, csv) while the test was running. In the debug mode the value was seen as same as the parameter name (name="borclu_id", value="borcluId"). 
Could anyone help? Is there any way to catch and record the value?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a scrape of the response, using a regular expression to capture and store the value into memory to use for subsequent requests.

Depending on your application, you may be able to strip the customer ID from the parameters and rely on a cookie manager to take care of it for you.